# Excel formula vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to fill in the **column D** using the information from **column G** (all in the first sheet) and the information from **column A** in the second sheet.

What needs to be returned to the column is the exact information found in the second sheet with the letter.

I have tried using vlookup with extract and other's but I always get N/A returned and im getting nervous.

Below are two screenshots of each sheet and at the bottom you will find an excel file uploaded with example data.

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

[Excel file with example](https://ufile.io/jas1u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an array. Remember to enter the formula with Ctrl+shift+enter

```
=INDEX(ActiveCoupons!A2:A9,MATCH(G3,RIGHT(ActiveCoupons!A2:A9,LEN(ActiveCoupons!A2:A9)-1)*1,0))
```

Comment: Its returning N/A

Comment: You need to enter it as an array. Instead of enter when you type in the formula, use ctrl+shift+enter - it should work then

Comment: Wow your right, what does that do? Never seen that function before.

Comment: It means that it is an array formula instead of a standard one. In this case it means that for A2 to A9 it does the functions to remove the letter at the front for each cell. It then matches and indexes.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Answer (score 0):

In 'ActiveCoupons' put in G2 : =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)*1

In 'ActiveCoupons' put in H2 : =A2

Expand the formulas to the rest of the columns G,H

In CouponRedemptionResults put in D2: =VLOOKUP(G2,ActiveCoupons!G:H,2,0)

Expand the formula to the rest of the columns D

Comment: HI Maksim. I want to do this all in one formula and in sheet "CouponRedemptionResults" only as this is the sheet I need to fill out.